# next dev and build gets stuck forever

Tags: next.js

Whenever I run `pnpm dev` it gets stuck at `ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000` without any errors and also doesn't start the server at localhost:3000 because when I hit the url on browser it doesn't loads the page

If I run `pnpm build` it also get stuck at `info  - Creating an optimized production build`

I tried deleting `/node_modules` and `.next` but not worked.
I also tried changing package manager (npm, yarn, pnpm) if that matters, still not worked

dependencies I am using are

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@next-auth/mongodb-adapter": "^1.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "mongodb": "^4.3.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.2.1",
    "next": "^12.2.2",
    "next-auth": "^4.9.0",
    "nextjs-progressbar": "^0.0.13",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-cool-inview": "^2.0.9",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-toastify": "9.0.5",
    "react-tooltip-lite": "^1.12.0",
    "react-typeme": "^1.0.1",
    "use-clipboard-copy": "^0.2.0"
  }
```

When I deploy it to vercel it builds and deploys completely fine ‍♂️

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know exactly how but my problem is solved!

**Here's what I did:**

1. Created a new next project
2. Tested is the new project working or not turn out to be not working
3. The problem started after I switched my project from YARN to PNPM, so removed all PNPM related files (lock file and node modules folder) and installed everything with NPM. Then I got to see finally some errors. It was something related to swc binaries (because probably SWC is not supported in Android)
4. Then, I created a `.babelrc` file and inside that file I wrote:

   ```json
   {
     "presets": ["next/babel"]
   }
   ```

   For more info: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/failed-loading-swc

After that my problem fixed!
I no longer got SWC minify feature in development phase but it's ok, because as I said that without `.babelrc` file, I mean without disabling SWC, it's working in vercel production/deployment.

Happy coding!

Comment: I switched from npm to pnpm and I faced the same issue. Is there another solution without babel

Comment: Switch back to npm and look for errors.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are on a compatible version of Node/NPM otherwise the build may hang like that and may not give any errors.

If it deploys ok on Netlify that's a good clue, check the version of what is running on their machine and try to apply the same locally.

Comment: It was a problem related to babelrc, I believe. Check the answer I already gave.